# ScalaTest: Is it possible to combine AsyncWordSpec and GuiceOneAppPerSuite

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I wanted to switch my Acceptance tests from `WordSpec` to `AsyncWordSpec`.

The existing trait looks like:

```
import org.scalatest.WordSpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite

class PetDBSpec
    extends WordSpec
    with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {
}
```

If I change that I have to `AsyncWordSpec` I have to change it like that:

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite

class PetDBSpec
    extends AsyncWordSpec
    with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {  this: TestSuite =>
}
```

But still get this Exception:

```
[error] ... class PetDBSpec needs to be abstract, since method withFixture in trait TestSuiteMixin of type (test: PetDBSpec.this.NoArgTest)org.scalatest.Outcome is not defined
[error] (Note that TestSuiteMixin.this.NoArgTest does not match AsyncTestSuite.this.NoArgAsyncTest)
```

It works fine with my UnitTests.

- Do I have to adjust my Tests?
- Or is it not possible to mix them?

Used Versions:

- Play: 2.6.15
- Scala Test: 3.0.5
- scalatestplus-play: 3.1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the open Issue in Github:

https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play/issues/112

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of GuiceOneAppPerSuite is below:

```
trait GuiceOneAppPerSuite 
    extends BaseOneAppPerSuite 
    with GuiceFakeApplicationFactory { this: TestSuite =>

}
```

From the above code you can see that GuiceOneAppPerSuite expects to be mixin with TestSuite.

```
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite

class PetDBSpec
    extends AsyncWordSpec
    with TestSuite
    with GuiceOneAppPerSuite { 

}
```

Comment: thanks - now I don't have any compile exception, but when running the tests I get `Empty test suite.` When using  `AsyncTestSuite` I have again compile problems.

Comment: try lowering the dependency version to a stable release

Comment: thanks I added my versions to the question - I think they are stable versions.